# Yii dynamic title tag

Tags: php, yii, title

I am doing a project in Yii framework now. i am concern about title tag and other meta tag which will be dynamic as well for SEO propose , The data for the tags will be fetched from database and displayed in the front-end.

What Should me my approach ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have basically two options here:

1. Subclass `CController`, create a `title` property like @PeterM suggested and then inherit your controllers from this controller.
2. [Define an app parameter](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/126/setting-and-getting-systemwide-static-parameters/) and echo that parameter in your layout. You can modify this from everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

In controller define:

```
public $title;
```

Then in your layout `echo` it into title tag.

```
<title><?= $this->title; ?></title>
```

In any action just assign `$title` and it will be displayed in layout title tag.

```
public function actionView()
{
    $this->title = 'My title fetched from DB'
}
```

Comment: Thanx for Your Idea @peterM , but there is different controller for different pages , I need a universal approach for all controllers